# How to clean speaker hole on macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

if you have macbook with thunderbolt - you will have some weird verry small hole on speaker. 
If this hole is dirty - HOW TO CLEAN IT ?

I have try with vacum cleaner nor air compressor not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something else to try:

Get a blob of an adhesive putty (such as [Blu Tack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu_Tack)), and work it until it's warm, pliable, and slightly sticky. Then push it fairly hard against the speaker hole, and remove it carefully. Repeat as needed.

The holes are too small for the putty to enter very far, but it will hopefully make contact with whatever's blocking them, which may then stick to the putty and be drawn out with it.

Of course, this method won't work for material that's embedded too deep, or stuck too hard. But it's quick, easy, and should do no harm.

(I find this is also a good way to remove dust and other debris from all sorts of objects, especially in nooks and crannies that are otherwise difficult to reach.)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you clean it from the back if you can open it to get there. If not, I would take something like a toothpick and put a piece of tissue on the end and inert in each hole in the cover being careful not to have dirt fall off inside. Probably doesn't matter if it does but I'd still be careful. I just counted the holes in the picture and there are about 1450 just in the picture with approximately 40 that are blocked. That works out to less than 3%. You can use this to determine if you wish to pursue this.